# React-router - navigating through history.push() refreshes the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, history

When I use a `<Link />` component, navigation happens smoothly without page refresh, but when I try to navigate through `history.push()` (i.e. on form submission), the page refreshes. How do I prevent `history.push()` from doing a refresh? Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import qs from 'query-string';

class SearchBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    this.props.history.push('?' + qs.stringify({search: this.state.value}));
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="searchbox">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="search"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            placeholder="Search..."
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(SearchBox);
```

Comment: two suggestions: 1. do `e.preventDefault()` first, 2. include a path in the `push` argument, e.g. `.push('/?' + ... )`

Comment: Suggestion 2 worked, thanks!

Comment: @ic3b3rg both are not working form me and i'm using functional component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment of @ic3b3rg:
Had to include a path in the argument for `push`:

```js
  handleSubmit(e) {
    this.props.history.push('/?' + qs.stringify({search: this.state.value}));
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

// ... Your codes

handleSubmit(e) {
  const historyBrowser = createBrowserHistory({
        basename: process.env.PUBLIC_URL,
        forceRefresh: false,
      });
  historyBrowser.push('?' + qs.stringify({search: this.state.value}));
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

If you set `forceRefresh: true` page will refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Make `e.preventDefault()` the first statement in the `handleSubmit()` function and then push the `url` to history.